# How can I work with Paypal Payouts on my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate Paypal Payouts to my React app. However, I am stuck at the AAC part where I generate a component to let the user connect.

I tried to either load the script in index.html or to load it using the paypal-checkout package.

In the first case, I get told that paypal isn't defined and in the second case, I get told that I can't get the property driver from undefined.

Here is my code and my index.html.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


const AACComponent = paypal.PayoutsAAC.driver('react', {
  React,
  ReactDOM
});

export class Affiliation extends Component {

  render () {
    const { t } = this.props;
    const { data, candidates, hirees } = this.state;
    return (
      <Screen type="background-white" loading={this.state.loading} title={this.props.t('pages:affiliation')}>
        <div className="container tw-space-y-3">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-6 tw-mx-auto">
              <div className="tw-card">
                <h2 className="tw-text-xl tw-font-bold">{t('affiliationHired')}</h2>
                <AACComponent
                clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID}
                merchantId={process.env.REACT_APP_PAYPAL_MERCHANT_ID}
                env={process.env.REACT_APP_PAYPAL_ENV}
                pageType="login"
                onLogin={() => {}} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </Screen>
    );
  }
}

Affiliation.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default withRouter(withTranslation('common')(Affiliation));
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="/" />
  </head>

  <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/payouts/js/payouts_aac.js"></script>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I removed the unecessary code to not clutter my code.

Any idea?

Comment: In the first example you need something like `import paypal from 'the-paypal-package'`

Comment: @jmargolisvt As I said in my post, when I try to use a package from PayPal it tells me I can't get the property driver from undefined.

Comment: Hey OP, did you figure out how to do this? Need ASAP haha